# SQL Boolean expression

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm new to SQL but I thought naively thought this would be simple.

I have a SQLITE table with FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME columns. I want to exclude specific individuals, e.g. 'Fred Smith' and 'Joe Bloggs'. I used the following:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, SURNAME
FROM MyTable
WHERE (FIRSTNAME != 'Fred' AND LASTNAME != 'Smith');
```

but that excludes all FIRSTNAMEs = 'Fred' and all LASTNAMEs = 'Smith'. How do I achieve what I need? Secondly, how do I achieve that for multiple individuals, i.e. 'Joe Bloggs' as well as 'Fred Smith'?

Comment: What happens if you switch AND to OR?

Answer (score 4):

> How do I achieve what I need?

```sql
SELECT FIRSTNAME,SURNAME FROM MyTable WHERE NOT (FIRSTNAME = 'Fred' AND LASTNAME = 'Smith');
```

[or the equivalent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

```sql
SELECT FIRSTNAME,SURNAME FROM MyTable WHERE (FIRSTNAME != 'Fred' OR LASTNAME != 'Smith');
```

> How do I achieve what I need? Secondly, how do I achieve that for multiple individuals, i.e. 'Joe Bloggs' as well as 'Fred Smith'?

Simply add the relevant AND clause.

```sql
SELECT FIRSTNAME,SURNAME FROM MyTable WHERE NOT (FIRSTNAME = 'Fred' AND LASTNAME = 'Smith') AND NOT (FIRSTNAME = 'Joe' AND LASTNAME = 'Bloggs');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `VALUES` to return all the names that you want to exclude and the `EXCEPT` operator to filter them out:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME FROM MyTable
EXCEPT
VALUES ('Fred', 'Smith'), ('Joe', 'Bloggs');
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=caf288d0738d7d20e6caf22b29a442a8).